# Add onClick event

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm having real trouble adding an `onClick` event to a script. Here's my code that basically shows Instagram photos. I want to add an `onclick="panel_five.show();return false"` to

```
<a href='" + data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url +"' >
    <img src='" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url +"' />
</a>
```

I'm having real trouble in syntax. Here's my complete code:

```
...
$('.ttl').first().parent().append('<div class="ttl"><div class="ttlpadding"><div class="item">' + "<a href='" + data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url +"' ><img src='" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url +"' /></a>" +"</div></div></div>");
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want.

```
$('.ttl').first().parent().append('<div class="ttl"><div class="ttlpadding"><div class="item">' + "<a href='" + data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url +"' onclick='panel_five.show();' ><img src='" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url +"' /></a>" +"</div></div></div>");
```

Comment: Yes. I needed this one only. Was getting confused b/w `''` and `""`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
     var parent = $('.ttl').first().parent();
     parent.append('<div class="ttl"><div class="ttlpadding"><div class="item">'
          + "<a href='" + data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url
          +"' ><img src='"+ data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url +"' /></a>"
          +"</div></div></div>"
     );
     parent.find('a').click(function() {
        // some code here
     });
});
```

Comment: or just add handler on click event for parent using event delegation. So it will be the best solution for you

Answer (score 1):

try this I have test with my url and image src and it work fine

```
$('.ttl').first().parent().append('<div class="ttl"><div class="ttlpadding"><div class="item">' + "<a href='" + data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url +"' ><img src='" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url +"' onclick='panel_five.show();return false;' /></a>" + '</div></div></div>');
```

Edit: If you have confused with " and ' you can use " and \" instead OR ' and \' as well

```
$("body").append("<a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">Stackoverflow</a>");
$('body').append('<a href=\'http://stackoverflow.com\'>Stackoverflow</a>');
```

It's view result in body tag as

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
<a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>Stackoverflow</a>
```